# Getting an object returned by an Oracle function using C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-functions

I'm working for a customer which gives me rights to execute functions and procedures from it Oracle database. I connot see them, nor tables or views or everything else.

I need to execute an Oracle function using c# .NET but I'm not able to get the object return by this function.

The following SQL query :

```
SELECT FOO.CUSTOMER_FUNCTION('FR', 'A00', 'AAA_12345') FROM dual;
```

returns this object :

```
FOO.CUSTOMER_OBJECT('YES',10,20.0,0,NULL)
```

And here is my c# method trying to get the object.
I simplified the method for the post.

#### Version 1

```
//using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

public Scoring Find(string p1, string p2, string p3)
{
    using (var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FOO.CUSTOMER_FUNCTION(:p1, :p2, :p3) FROM dual";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", p3);

        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Throws an OracleException :

```
"ORA-12570: Network session: unexpected packet read error"
```

#### Version 2

```
//using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

public Scoring Find(string p1, string p2, string p3)
{
    using (var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FOO.CUSTOMER_FUNCTION(:p1, :p2, :p3) FROM dual";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", p3);

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Throws an IOException :

```
"Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
```

#### Version 3

```
//using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

public Scoring Find(string p1, string p2, string p3)
{
    using (var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FOO.CUSTOMER_FUNCTION(:p1, :p2, :p3) FROM dual";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", p3);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Does not throw exception but naturally I cannot get data...

#### Version 4

```
//using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

public Scoring Find(string p1, string p2, string p3)
{
    using (var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "FOO.CUSTOMER_FUNCTION";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ReturnValue", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", p3);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Throws an OracleException :

```
"ORA-06550: Line 1, column 15 :
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: Line 1, column 7 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored"
```

#### Version 5

```
//using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

public Scoring Find(string p1, string p2, string p3)
{
    using (var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "FOO.CUSTOMER_FUNCTION";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p1", p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2", p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3", p3);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Throws an OracleException :

```
"ORA-06550: Line 1, Column 7 :
PLS-00221: 'CUSTOMER_FUNCTION' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: Line 1, Column 7 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored"
```

Can someone help me ?

I don't know if I am precise enough...

PS : Please forgive my frenchy english...

Comment: Oh I misread you that you want to call Stored procedure for some reason ..

Comment: But everything I read execute Oracle functions like stored procedures, so what you submited to me did not disturb me...

Comment: see version 3 with executeScallar not executenonquery

Comment: The 3rd version with ExecuteScalar is the 1st version